# How do I achieve a guest wifi set up with a Draytek AP810 and a Netgear GS728TPv2?

Tags: switch, wifi, vlan

We have recently moved offices and so our facilities are bit more limited than they were before.

We have a basic internet router (a BT Smart Hub for UK people) that doesn't have VLAN options and 4 LAN ports.

I have two Draytek AP810 access points, and I would like one to be the employee WiFi and one the Guest WiFi.

I do have a Netgear GS728TPv2 Smart Switch, which seems to have all sorts of options, but I am not familiar with using switches for this kind of thing and I am not even sure if it is possible since I am guessing that ultimately, everything will be able to communicate via the hub in the internet router